# Was Jerome K Jerome politically active?

Tags: jerome-k-jerome

Jerome K. Jerome's short story "The New Utopia" has a strongly anti-socialist and anti-democratic message.

> I  had  spent  an  extremely  interesting  evening.    I  had  dined  with
>   some  very  "advanced"  friends  of  mine  at  the  “National  Socialist
>   Club”.    We  had  had  an  excellent  dinner:  the  pheasant,  stuffed  with
>   truffles,  was  a  poem;  and  when  I  say  that  the  ’49  Chateau  Lafitte
>   was  worth  the  price  we  had  to  pay  for  it,  I  do  not  see  what  more  I can add in its favour.
>
> After dinner, and over the cigars (I must say they do know how
>   to  stock  good  cigars  at  the  National  Socialist  Club),  we  had  a  very instructive  discussion  about  the  coming  equality  of  man  and  the
>   nationalisation of capital.
>
> I  was  not  able  to  take  much  part  in  the  argument  myself,  be-
>   cause,  having  been  left  when  a  boy  in  a  position  which  rendered  it necessary  for  me  to  earn  my  own  living,  I  have  never  enjoyed  the time and opportunity to study these questions.

The first person narrator then fell asleep, and woke up in the future. His guide took him on a walk around the city, and said

> “Why, I thought you understood that all men were now equal.  What would become  of  our  equality  if  one  man  or  woman  were  allowed  to swagger  about  in  golden  hair,  while  another  had  to  put  up  with carrots?    Men  have  not  only  got  to  be  equal  in  these  happy  days, but  to  look  it,  as  far  as  can  be.    By  causing  all  men  to  be  clean shaven,  and  all  men  and  women  to  have  black  hair  cut  the  same length, we obviate, to a certain extent, the errors of Nature.” 
>   I said:
>   “Why black?”
>   He  said  he  did  not  know,  but  that  was  the  colour  which  had
>   been decided upon.
>   “Who by?” I asked.
>   “By THE MAJORITY,” he replied, raising his hat and lowering his eyes, as if in prayer.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_K._Jerome#Early_life) says

> He wished to go into politics or be a man of letters, but the death of his father when Jerome was 13 and of his mother when he was 15 forced him to quit his studies and find work to support himself.

Did he publicly support the Conservative party, or speak publicly about current political issues, other than in this story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his autobiography, *[My Life and Times](https://archive.org/details/mylifetimes0000jero/page/102/mode/2up)* (page 102 in the edition linked at Internet Archive) Jerome writes:

> I was a die-hard Tory at twenty-five and Whibley was an anarchist of the reddest dye. We had some grand sets-to. John Burns was preaching revolution and the British Constitution was in danger. Whibley wanted to go a-rioting in Trafalgar Square. We had difficulty restraining him. To make things safe, I joined the special constables and learnt to form fours and to turn my eyes right and left. Now I am a Vice-President, I believe, of the Oxford University Labour Party, while Whibley has become a pillar of the State, and writes for stodgy, old *Blackwood*.

[Charles Whibley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Whibley) was an English literary journalist and author;
[John Burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Burns) was an English trade unionist and politician;
*Blackwood* refers to [Blackwood's Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackwood%27s_Magazine).

He also writes at page 176, in relating a holiday in Switzerland before the First World War:

> It was election time in England, and the hotel crowd used to encourage Kipling and myself to political argument in the great hall. I suppose I was the only man in the hotel who was not a die-hard conservative. Kipling himself was always courteous, but not all the peppery old colonels from Cheltenham and fierce old ladies from Bath were. Notwithstanding, on wet afternoons, when one couldn't go out, it wasn't bad sport. Conan Doyle in his memoirs writes me down as one 'hot-headed and intolerant in political matters'. When I read the passage I was most astonished. It is precisely what I should have said myself concerning Doyle. I suppose the fact is that tolerance is another name for indifference.

It is unlikely that his claim to uncertainty over holding office in the Oxford University Labour party is intended to be taken as more than an indication of having generally moved away from strong support of the Conservative Party. He was never a student at Oxford, though I don't know if that would be a pre-requisite for such an office holder.

From these extracts I would understand that he did not shy away from discussion of politics in public, and that he certainly didn't regard himself as indifferent to political matters. But I have not found any sign that he campaigned for or represented any particular party.

Comment: Interesting thanks followup - here https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69173/was-jerome-k-jerome-vice-president-of-the-oxford-university-labour-party